# Laravel-VueJS axios URL shows 404 error on shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, axios, hosting

My Laravel VueJS Application work fine in local server. But when I uploaded it to the shared hosting, it gives problem with url.

In local environment, the code works fine with:

```
axios.get('/api/get/users')
```

But, in production server, since it is shared hosting, codes need to be change like:

```
axios.get('http://www.example.com/public/myApp/public/api/get/users')
```

Is there any way to use same url on local & production server without changing?

Comment: I don't see why you should change on the production server

Comment: Because it is hosted on shared hosting so, it results 404 error... When I track url... it shows `http://www.example.com/api/get/users`
Instead of `http://www.example.com/public/myApp/public/api/get/users`